# ADFS 3.0 tokenlifetime

Tags: oauth-2.0, active-directory, access-token, adfs

We have a setup with an AD server and AD FS server. We are not using Azure AD FS.

We want to change the tokenlifetime, and when we set it to:
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetIdentity  -tokenlifetime  we see that the tokenlifetime parameter is set to the amount of minutes we set it to.

The problem however is that on the receiving end the token expire time is 43200, which corresponds to 12 hours. It doesn't matter if we set it to a higher or lower number than 12 hours. Even setting it to 0, which should default to 60 minutes sets it to 12 hours.

After a lot of digging and research I've found this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

The interesting part is this quote:

"Token Max Age (issued for federated users who have insufficient revocation information1)   Refresh tokens (issued for federated users who have insufficient revocation information1)   12 hours
Refresh Token Max Inactive Time (issued for confidential clients)   Refresh tokens (issued for confidential clients)    90 days
Refresh Token Max Age (issued for confidential clients) Refresh tokens (issued for confidential clients)    Until-revoked
1Federated users who have insufficient revocation information include any users who do not have the "LastPasswordChangeTimestamp" attribute synced. These users are given this short Max Age because AAD is unable to verify when to revoke tokens that are tied to an old credential (such as a password that has been changed) and must check back in more frequently to ensure that the user and associated tokens are still in good standing. To improve this experience, tenant admins must ensure that they are syncing the “LastPasswordChangeTimestamp” attribute (this can be set on the user object using Powershell or through AADSync)."

Like I already mentioned, we're not using AAD so we cannot use the AADsync method. (We might switch to AAD, but for right now we want to keep the ADFS inhouse). I do however suspect the above quote to be the cause of our problems, since it is the same behavior (tokenlifetime of 12 hours), even though it doesn't matter if we set it to less than 12 hours.

Is there a way for us to sync the LastPasswordChangeTimestamp in any way shape or form in the AD FS? I have setup a claim towards the AD to the ADFS so I can from the token received see the timestamp for when the password was changed (LDAP timeformat). So it seems to be synced somehow. We are atleast assuming that is the problem right now. Or is there a way to enforce tokenlifetime and disregard the lastpasswordchanged timestamp?

Or might the problem be elsewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found any way to control refresh token expiration?  We are using ADFS 4.0 (2016) and need to do the same.  Basically we need "offline_access".

Comment: We were unable to change any timers, timers were changed visually when we check AdfsProperties and RelayingPartytrust but the actual timers remained the same. But check Get-AdfsProperties there's a couple of interesting choices there:
SsoLifetime and PersistentSsoLifetimeMins